# Foreign Keys in web2py

Tags: python, mysql, data-access-layer, web2py

I keep getting this error: 
 **'DAL' object has no attribute 'event_instance'**

it points to my db_agents file as the culprit on this line:

`('event_instance_id', db.event_instance)`

However if I move the definition of the event_instance table to that db_agents model file the error disappears, but I get a new one referering to another FKey in the event_instance tbl. Is there a way to avoid having all my db.define_tables in the same file, I would like to keep them separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Field('event_instance_id', 'reference event_instance')
```

Using that alternative syntax, it is not necessary for the "event_instance" table to be defined already.

Also, note that model files are executed in alphabetical order, so your original code will work as long as the "event_instance" table is defined in a model file that comes earlier in alphabetical order.

Comment: I get a different error now,even though I exclusively use 'references' in foreign key definations. I thought it doesn't matter which order I define table as long as I use references instead of db.tbl.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else wrong. If you use the above syntax, you do not have to have the event_instance table defined already. It's impossible to say what your problem is if you show neither the code nor the error you are receiving.